# Problem with adding plug-in spy capabilities to an RCP application

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

As some of you may know, Eclipse IDE has a nice feature called "Plug-in Spy". 
I would like to add this feature to my own RCP application. Now, I added the org.eclipse.pde.runtime to my list of dependencies, and since I defined a different key binding schema, I also created a command that points to SpyHandler, and I defined a key binding  that binds a certain key combination in a given context. 
Now the problem is, the command is executed, but I get the following exception:

```
KEYS >>> WorkbenchKeyboard.executeCommand(commandId = 'org.eclipse.pde.ui.spy.commands.spyCommand', parameters = {})
16:00:52,107 WARN [ErrorReporter] - Error Reporter invoked to handle java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.runtime.spy.dialogs.SpyDialog.createDialogArea(SpyDialog.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.runtime.spy.dialogs.SpyDialog.createContents(SpyDialog.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.runtime.spy.handlers.SpyHandler.execute(SpyHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.executeCommand(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.press(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.processKeyEvent(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.filterKeySequenceBindings(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.access$3(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1052)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1103)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.sendKeyEvent(Shell.java:1361)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1099)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1508)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4268)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(Canvas.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4160)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1598)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2038)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4873)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2459)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3655)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)

    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.runtime.PDERuntimePluginImages.makeIconURL(PDERuntimePluginImages.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.runtime.PDERuntimePluginImages.create(PDERuntimePluginImages.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.runtime.PDERuntimePluginImages.<clinit>(PDERuntimePluginImages.java:43)
    ... 50 more
```

Can anybody help me with this? Is it possible that I'm missing something in my target (it's a custom built target)? And if so, what? I added org.eclipse.pde.runtime, and, as far as I can see, no other plugin should be necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [install plugin spy plugin into custom rcp application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332079/install-plugin-spy-plugin-into-custom-rcp-application)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to create a new command? You can bind an existing command in your keybinding schema and assign new keys.

Comment: I tried to do that, but that didn't work. I tried specifying both org.eclipse.pde.ui.spy.commands.spyCommand and org.eclipse.pde.runtime.spy.commands.spyCommand. None of those worked. I had to create a command with that id and assign SpyHandler as it's default handler. The command is now executed, but as you can see, I'm getting an error.

Comment: org.eclipse.pde.runtime.spy.commands.spyCommand is the right id. Can you paste the plugin.xml?