# install plugin spy plugin into custom rcp application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

Plugin spy is included into Eclipse since 3.4. I wonder if there is somewhere separate plugin distribution, so it could be used to install into custom rcp application. In my case it is jubula if this information is necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Plug-in Registry view, you can see the spy is defined in `org.eclipse.pde.runtime`. Just include this in your application. The only mandatory dependencies are for `org.eclipse.core.runtime`, `org.eclipse.ui`, and `org.eclipse.ui.forms` - the rest are optional...

Comment: How can I include this plugin? I do not build application, that is already shipped one.

Comment: I haven't found an existing feature, apart from `org.eclipse.pde`, that includes the plug-in. But you could make a feature with the plug-in yourself..

Comment: Could you explain in a few words, why do I need a feature to install a plugin? Why can not I just copy plugin jar file to plugins directory of eclipse installation?

Comment: Eclipse - actually OSGi - does not provision plug-ins _just_ because they are present in the file system. OSGi must be told. That can be done in a number of ways. The typical being dropping plug-ins in the `dropins` directory or installing them via Eclipse as a feature. The former have all sort of problems - e.g. these plug-ins cannot be updated and can completely ruin your installation - where the later are 1st class citizens.