# Eclipse Plugin for existing editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin, editor, content-assist

I would like to make a plugin that contributes to the content assist menu in the Java editor. I would like to suggest some options, insert code and get the code from the editor. Is this possible? All that I have found so far is creation of new editors, but I just need to mess with the existing ones. Can this be achieved? How should I even start? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10332079/796559

Comment: @Bananeweizen, your answer solved my problems, so if you post it as an asnwer, I will accept it.